# RMarkdown button to show or hide code

Tags: r, markdown

I am often writing markdown documents that get read by both technical people and executives.

In that sense, I was wondering if its possible to create a button in the HTML that would hide or show the code chunks in the final output?

Currently, I am creating two seperate files, which I think is a less elegant solution.

Anyone?

Comment: This is explained here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#code_folding

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I was looking for. Awesome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@docendo discimus provided a [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#code_folding) that answers the OP question. I'm including the code here for posterity purposes.

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---
```

Which produces the code folding button:
[image]